# MapView mapType `.standard` iOS17 does not allow 3d

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am working on a virtual simulator for iOS 17 from my Macbook.

I want to have the initial view present the Map but zoomed out enough so that it's basically showing the whole world - in a 3d render.

My understanding is that as of iOS17 if you have `.standard` for the `MKMapView` type, it should still render as 3D if the altitude is high enough. But on my simulator, I literally cannot zoom out any further.

Is the right protocol to update the mapType to be `.hybridFlyover`? That seems different than the `.standard` (which I think is what I actually want).

Does anyone have any idea / is there anything sticking out in this code?

Here is my code:

```
struct GlobeView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var coordinates: [IdentifiableCoordinate]

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.mapType = .hybridFlyover
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        let camera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenter: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0), fromDistance: 1_000_000_000, pitch: 0, heading: 0)
        mapView.setCamera(camera, animated: true)
        
        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        let annotations = coordinates.map { coordinate -> MKPointAnnotation in
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = coordinate.coordinate
            return annotation
        }
        uiView.addAnnotations(annotations)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var parent: GlobeView

        init(_ parent: GlobeView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
}
```

---

### **UPDATE**

I have received the suggestion to use `preferredConfiguration` given `mapType` is deprecated with iOS17 which is a good point.

However, even with:

```
mapViewModel.mapView.preferredConfiguration = MKStandardMapConfiguration(elevationStyle: .realistic)
```

I am still not able to see the whole globe on zooming out. I have to use MKHybrid or MKImagery which does not seem right.

Comment: Do you realise that `mapType` is deprecated in iOS 17? Try setting the `preferredConfiguration` instead. For example, set it to a `MKStandardMapConfiguration` with a `.realistic` elevation style.

Comment: @Sweeper hey sorry about that - I did not realize that it was deprecated, but I have already tried to use the `preferredConfiguration` with `.realistic` elevation, and I am still not able to see the whole glob.